# Subir una imagen a MYSQL desde ANDROID con un webservice PHP

Tags: php, android

Android:

```
private String convertirimagen(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,70,stream);
    byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(bytes,Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

PHP:

```
    $v1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['1']);
    $v2 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['2']);
    $v3 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['3']);
    $v4 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['4']);
    $v5 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['5']);
    $v6 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['6']);
    $v7 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['7']);
    $v8 = $mysqli->real_escape_string(base64_decode($_REQUEST['8']));

    $rf1 = f1($v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$v8);
```

Esto no funciona:

```
function f1($v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$v8){
global $mysqli;
$data=array();

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `usuarios`(`codigo`, `nombres`, `apellidop`, `apellidom`, `foto`, `correo`, `password`, `ntelefono`, `activo`, `tipouser`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$a = 1;
$t = 2;
$null = null;
$stmt->bind_param('isssbssiii',$v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$null,$v5,$v6,$v7,$a,$t);
$stmt->send_long_data(4, $v8);
if ($stmt->execute()){

    $data [] = array('mensaje'=>'Registrado con exito');
    return $data;
}}
```

Pero aquí normal corre:

```
function f1($v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$v8){
global $mysqli;
$data=array();

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `usuarios`(`codigo`, `nombres`, `apellidop`, `apellidom`, `foto`, `correo`, `password`, `ntelefono`, `activo`, `tipouser`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,'$v8',?,?,?,?,?)");
$a = 1;
$t = 2;
$stmt->bind_param('isssssiii',$v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$a,$t);
if ($stmt->execute()){

    $data [] = array('mensaje'=>'Registrado con exito');
    return $data;
}}
```

Comment: ¿En la última función dices que el código va bien? Entonces, ¿cuál es en sí el problema? Ah, si ya `$data` está declarado como array, entonces: `$data ['mensaje'] = 'Registrado con exito';`, porque de lo contrario, tendrás `mensaje` en un array dentro del array `$data` y para leer el mensaje tendrás que usar dos bucles o dos índices.

Comment: la variable $v8 no la estoy mandando como parámetro, es una mala practica creo.

Comment: Ah ya. Sí, es una mala práctica.  ¿Qué error te está dando la primera función?

Comment: Quizá tengas que modificar el valor de [`max_allowed_packet`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html) en caso de que estés recibiendo el error ***packet too large*** o algo parecido.